# Connections between Merton Fraction & Kelly Criterion

Tags: portfolio-optimization, kelly-criterion, position-sizing

What are the theoretical and practical connections between the solution to the [Merton's Portfolio problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merton%27s_portfolio_problem) and a bet-sizing tool such as optimizing the expected value of the logarithm of wealth (aka [the Kelly Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelly_criterion))?

Will these two solutions converge under certain conditions?

For example, the Kelly Criterion considers a two-outcome bet scenario and determines the optimal betting level depending on your bankroll. The Merton formula

$$ \pi(W,t) = \frac {\mu - r } {\sigma ^ 2 \gamma} $$

which is a combination of the mean-variance expected return and a risk aversion. If $r=0$ as it does in the Kelly formula, and a log-utility that the Kelly criterion assumes, do these results agree?

Comment: Yes, log utility implies $\gamma=1$ so Merton's result reduces to Kelly's in that case.

Comment: seconded - they agree at merton's gamma equals 1. The "problem" is between Merton plus Kelly versus all other frameworks that would never lever up multiples of wealth to bet, if the economic textbooks were correct.